# How to make sure a pdf file is always downloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf, download

I need to create a link for downloading a pdf file .

But sometimes the pdf file will open in the browser and sometimes it will get downloaded.

How can I make sure that the pdf file is always downloaded.

Comment: Does it depend on the browser you're using?

Answer (score 0):

As this question is a duplicate, I'll just answer to make the answer more clear. Create a php page like this:

**myFile.pdf.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="path/to/your/file.pdf"');
?>
```

and if you call this page (e.g. `http://domain.com/myFile.pdf`) it will download the pdf file. Make sure this page and the actual file don't have the same exact name and location!